# Meteor - When using check roles wont work

Tags: meteor

I'm having a problem with a publish function. If I run the code without the roles package it works, however, when I add the roles `if statement` it doesn't. What am I missing here?

Path: `publish.js` **(working)**

```
Meteor.publish('userProfile', function(id) {
  check(id, String);
  return Meteor.users.find({_id: id}, {
    fields: { 
      "profile.firstName": 1, 
      "profile.familyName": 1
    }
  });
});
```

Path: `publish.js` **(not working)**

```
Meteor.publish('userProfile', function(group, id) {
  if (Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, ['is_admin'], group)) {

  check(id, String);
  return Meteor.users.find({_id: id}, {
    fields: { 
      "profile.firstName": 1, 
      "profile.familyName": 1
    }
  });

  } else {

// user not authorized. do not publish secrets
this.stop();
return;

}
});
```

Comment: Try replacing the else block with `return this.ready();`. That indicates that the publication has ended without sending data to client.

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work. Is it something to do with `Meteor.publish('userProfile', function(group, id)`

Comment: Can you clarify what isn't working?

Comment: @oscar is it a good idea simply to `return null;` ?

Comment: It seems to load the page however roles doesn't work. So if I'm is_teacher trying to log into is_admin it will let me. I have the roles restrictions setup and working in other parts so that isn't the problem. The problem appears to be something with check or the way I've written the function.

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen I don't think so, I understand that `return null;` doesn't mark the end of the subscription process to the client and the client will wait forever for the subscription.

Comment: @Oscar I just looked through [roles package](https://atmospherejs.com/alanning/roles) and they are suggesting what OP has already done: `this.stop(); return;`. So it is a bit confusing as to what is the best practice: do you have any links I could look up on this issue?

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen Sorry for the delay. [Meteor guide - publications](http://guide.meteor.com/data-loading.html#publications). Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look it up. @oscar